# How to move Structures and Templates from liferay 6.0 to liferay 6.1?

Tags: java, liferay, portal

We are having a liferay portal 6.0 community edition running on tomcat server, there are lot of structures, templates and Articles on that server.

Now, we are planning to migrate to liferay portal 6.1, We have liferay portal 6.1 on separate server, I need to move all the structures and templates from 6.0 to 6.1 server.

I tried importing as lar, but it is giving some errors, saying the build no. of the lar files does not match, then after doing some search in liferay forums, I found that we cannot import a lar between different versions.

Also, I tried to run some migration scripts found in liferay forums, but they are giving lot of errors. Is there any easy way to migrate the Articles, Structures and templates from Liferay6.0 to Liferay6.1 Community Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this should be handled by the database upgrade script Liferay executes automatically when it discovers that a newer Liferay release is using an older database schema. So basically what you should do is:

1. Create a copy of your 6.0 database schema
2. Let a fresh Liferay 6.1 point to the copied schema and start the server. The upgrade script will now run. Have some patience :)

Good luck!